# Proof Help regarding Limit Differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f’(a) = M$ where $M > 0$. Prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} > M/2$.

I am probably making this problem harder than it is. I would appreciate a push in the right direction. The solution isn't coming to me. Thanks!

Comment: If the derivative is $M$, then as $x \to a$ the difference quotient approaches $M$, and so must eventually be larger than $M/2$ when $x$ is near enough to $a$.

Comment: Consider using [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Comment: The way it is phrased now, this is not true. Consider $f(x)=0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f'(a)=0 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ but the difference quotient does not exist, so certainly it cannot be positive.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\frac{M}{2}$  is positive (it is equal to $\frac{M}{2}$)  then the function where you apllied the limit is positive in a reduced neighborhood of $a$.
That is $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\frac{M}{2}>0$ in a reduced neighborhood , as you wanted to prove.

Comment: to gt6989b : the question asks to prove in a reduced neighborhood so the point a is not  included.

Comment: This is a delta-epsilon proof. I believe that the problem should be set up as [(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)] - M < M/2 and should show that  if 0<x-a<delta, then f(x)-f(a)>0.

Comment: There is a well  known result about limits that is : if the limit of a function is positive then the function is positive in a reduce eighborhood of the point the variable coverges, I used this result.

Comment: My professor hinted the following: f''(a)=M means lim(x>a) (f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)=M. (I understand this part)
Now apply the definition of limit with epsilon=M/2.
Try to deduce that if 0<x-a<delta, then f(x)-f(a)>0. (I don't understand how to do this part).